# How to sync data from SFMC Data Extension to sObject in Salesforce org?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I have created a data extension in Salesforce Marketing Cloud(SFMC). Data in this data extension gets updated at certain point of time. I want to sync the data of this data extension to a sObject in Salesforce.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no straight forward way to do this. You would have to use SSJS to make API calls to the sObject you want to update. With the exception of email tracking data, the flow of data between Salesforce.org and SFMC is mostly unidirectional

Comment: Where can I use SSJS? I mean in Automation Studio or somewhere else? Actually, I am using MobileConnect and SMS, when a user sends a reply to a SMS I am storing user's reply in the Data Extension. Now, I want to sync this user's reply to a sObject in Salesforce. So, Where should I write SSJS? Please guide me on this.

Comment: Automation Studio. You run it as a `Script Activity`. You can also fire the API using AMPScript but this will involve using an Email/ Landing Page

Comment: Actually, I am using MobileConnect and SMS, when a user sends a reply to a SMS I am storing user's reply in the Data Extension. Now, I want to sync this user's reply to a sObject in Salesforce. So, can I write SSJS in SMS along with AmpScript?